# Error while changing the symbol of a layer in QGIS in plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I am trying to add a feature then trying to change shape and size of feature like below:-

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=EPSG:4326', 'point' , "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("ID", QVariant.Int)])
pt = QgsFeature()
layer.startEditing()
point1 = QgsPoint(float(lon),float(lat))
pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point1))
pt.setAttributes([inputid])
pr.addFeatures([pt])
layer.updateExtents()
layer.commitChanges()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
symbol_layer = QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayerV2()
symbol_layer.setSize(5.0)
symbol_layer.setColor(QColor(255,0,0,255))
layer.rendererV2().symbols()[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)
```

but this give me error :-

```
layer.rendererV2().symbols()[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 4):

Using only the relevant parts of your code and adding only one more line:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
symbol_layer = QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayerV2()
symbol_layer.setSize(5.0)
symbol_layer.setColor(QColor(255,0,0,255))
layer.rendererV2().symbols()[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)
properties = symbol_layer.properties()
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

I get the expected result without any problem. It seems that you set the symbol layer in the right way (in fact, the last line in my code simply *repaints* the layer).

Comment: the above code works fine in python console but when i add this to my plugin it still gives this error :-                                                                                             layer.rendererV2().symbols()[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @vaibhavDhiman you didn't specify it, but I'm not sure that the error it is related to it.