# Increasing size and changing color in centroids, lines, and polygons

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, color

In the QGIS python console, I am able to get the active layer with `layer = iface.activeLayer()` but I need to be able to change the size and color of both centroids and polygons.  For a polygon layer, this can change the outline width and the fill color:

```
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
    myVectorLayer = layer
    myRenderer  = layer.rendererV2()
    if layer.geometryType() == QGis.Polygon:
        mySymbol1 = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple({'color':'blue', 
                                                  'color_border':'black',
                                                  'width_border':'.5'})
        myRenderer.setSymbol(mySymbol1)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

If a centroid layer is selected, and the same approach is used, but with `if layer.geometryType() == QGis.Point:`.  Things don't work as expected.  The color of the centroid turns transparent. The color is applied in the legend.  And, sometimes this code produces a minidump and crash.  Since it is easy to change the size and color of a centroid, using properties, style, single symbol, then size and color; the question remains: Is it possible to do this via python?  I suppose that `QgsCentroidFillSymbolLayerV2` might work but I can't figure out how to use it to change line size or color.

```
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
    myVectorLayer = layer
    myRenderer  = layer.rendererV2()
    if layer.geometryType() == QGis.Point:
        mySymbol1 = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple({'color':'red', 
                                                  'color_border':'black',
                                                  'width_border':'0'})
        myRenderer.setSymbol(mySymbol1)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

For lines:  If a line layer is loaded and selected, trying to change the color  and size of the line, at the same time and "on-the-fly", with the following code, will crash qGIS.

```
    vlayer = iface.activeLayer()
    props = { 'color' : 'yellow' }
    sl = QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry.instance().symbolLayerMetadata("SimpleLine").createSymbolLayer(props)
    s = QgsLineSymbolV2([sl])
    vlayer.setRendererV2( QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2( s ) )
    symbols = vlayer.rendererV2().symbols()
    symbol = symbols[0]
    symbol.setWidth(2)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

If the layer is deleted and reloaded, the following sometimes works, sometimes crashes. Note, [Define pen width of a Line layer in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214611/define-pen-width-of-a-line-layer-in-pyqgis) writes that `setWidth` should be used instead of `width`.

```
    props = { 'width' : '1', 'color' : 'blue' }
    sl = QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry.instance().symbolLayerMetadata("SimpleLine").createSymbo        lLayer(props)
    s = QgsLineSymbolV2([sl])
    vlayer.setRendererV2( QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2( s ) )
    symbols = vlayer.rendererV2().symbols()
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

This changes the width of the line, with no attempt to change the color, and without crashes.

```
    symbols = vlayer.rendererV2().symbols()
    symbol = symbols[0]
    symbol.setWidth(1)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

This, adapted from [How to set Marker Line symbol for QgsVectorLayer by using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59682/how-to-set-marker-line-symbol-for-qgsvectorlayer-by-using-python) , changes the line width and color, and with no crashes:

```
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
    registry = QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry.instance()
    lineMeta = registry.symbolLayerMetadata("SimpleLine")
    symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    # Line layer
    lineLayer = lineMeta.createSymbolLayer({'width': '1', 'color': 'red', 'offset': '-1.0', 'penstyle': 'solid', 'use_custom_dash': '0', 'joinstyle': 'bevel', 'capstyle': 'square'})
    # Replace the default layer with our two custom layers
    symbol.deleteSymbolLayer(0)
    symbol.appendSymbolLayer(lineLayer)
    # Replace the renderer of the current layer
    renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2(symbol)
    layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
```

Centroid size and color, taken from:  [Error while changing the symbol of a layer in QGIS in plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239538/error-while-changing-the-symbol-of-a-layer-in-qgis-in-plugin).  This works inside the qGIS python console but throws an indent error (that I am trying to resolve) when loaded as part of a qGis plug-in.

```
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    symbol_layer = QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayerV2()
    symbol_layer.setSize(8.0)
    symbol_layer.setColor(QColor(224,242,0))
    layer.rendererV2().symbols()[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)
    properties = symbol_layer.properties()
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]

Fixed:  I had pasted in my code.  Somehow a "space" or "tab" was not correctly formatted, hence the indentation error.  So, the above will work in a plugin, and to change a centroid's size and color.  Here's another way to do the same thing:

```
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    renderer = layer.rendererV2()
    symbol1 = QgsMarkerSymbolV2.createSimple({'color': 'yellow','size':'8'})
    renderer.setSymbol(symbol1) 
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```